# Line equation in polar coordinates does not hold

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

I am having trouble understanding how linear equations in polar coordinates work.

Say I have two points on the same line: $(1,1)$ and $(3,3)$.

[image: plot]

Then for the equation 
$$b=y-mx,$$
$b=0$ and $m=1$ holds for the two points.

But for the equation $$r=x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta,$$
with $\theta=45\pi/180$, $r$ is different;  it's $1.4$ for $(1,1)$ and $4.2$ for $(3,3)$.

I don't understand; shouldn't $r$ be constant?

Comment: Do you know what $r$ is supposed to represent in polar coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Given is $$ y =x $$ Convert it to polar coordinates.

$$ r \cos \theta = r \sin \theta  $$ Now divide by $r$,

$$  \tan \theta = m = 1  $$  for all $r$, independent of $r$. Means in polar coordinates the straight line through origin does not involve radius $r$. It should not be a constant, it should not appear anywhere at all.

That is its *definition*, holds well, makes sense is it not?

Answer (score 0):

$$ y = mx + b $$
Since $m=1$ and $b=0$, we have
$$ y = x $$
Converting to polar coordinates yields
$$ r\sin\phi = r\cos\phi $$
$$ r\sin\phi - r\cos\phi = 0 $$
$$ r\left(\sin\phi - \cos\phi\right) = 0 $$
At point $(1, 1)$, we have
$$ r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt{1^2+1^2} = \sqrt{2} $$
$$ \phi = \mathbb{atan2}\left(y, x\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)= \frac{\pi}{4} $$
So now
$$ \sqrt2\left(\sin \frac{\pi}{4} - \cos \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \sqrt2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)=0 $$
Try it yourself with points $(3,3)$ and $(4,4)$. If you get a mismatch, then you likely evaluated $\mathbb{atan2}$ incorrectly. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).